# Setting up per user JWT claim Named Credential

Tags: oauth2, namedcredentials, jwt, external-services

I'm trying to setup a per-user JWT claim as per the documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_create_edit_oath_ext_cred.htm&type=5) the issue is it specifies

> Subject of the token (the user).
>
> The subject is a string when the identity type is named principal, and
> it’s a formula when the identity type is per user.

The issue I have is what is actually accessible from this?

I have tried the below:

> $User.FederationIdentifier

> {!User.FederationIdentifier}

And it doesn't seem to merge them into the claim am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation is not clear.

After a few tries, it worked with {!$User.FederationIdentifier}

Comment: Thank you so much it was just so annoying with no examples the documentation felt lacking.